# Timeout occurs while executing MySqlDataReader::Read()

Tags: c#, mysql

I get the following exception while calling Read() on a MySqlDataReader object.

```
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString))
{
     con.Open();
     using (MySqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand())
     {
         command.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT ID FROM MyTable WHERE ID IN ({0})", idList.ToString());
         MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
         while (reader.Read())
         {
             int id = Int32.Parse(reader["ID"].ToString());
             if (!idHashSet.Contains(id))
             {
                 idHashSet.Add(id);
             }                         
         }
    }
}
```

The program seems to freeze for about 8 hours, and then finally spits out the following exception and stack trace.

```
Timeout can be only be set to 'System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite' or a value > 0.
Parameter name: value
   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.set_ReadTimeout(Int32 value)
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.StartTimer(IOKind op)
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.FetchDataRow(Int32 statementId, Int32 columns)
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.NextRow(CommandBehavior behavior)
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Read()
```

The same error is occurring at a different section of code around the same time, which reads from a completely different table from a different server, so I am inclined to think that the problem exists on the client side.  Any suggestions?

Comment: _The program seems to freeze for about 8 hours_ Wow o.O

Comment: Did you checked, at that time any bulk DML was happening on MyTable? Your query looks pretty straight forward.

Comment: Yes, a bulk delete was occurring on MyTable around the same time, which took 137 seconds.  However, no delete was occurring on the 2nd table which I mention above, yet the same error still occurred.

Comment: The 8 hour wait is likely occurring because of either interactive_timeout or wait_timeout on the mysql server side, which are both set to 28800.

Comment: How many ids are in your idlist?

Comment: The list has 917 ids.

Answer (score 2):

Could well be this bug here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75604

If `Environment.TickCount` rolls over (after 24.9 days of server uptime) whilst you're executing a command then the connector will throw the exact exception you are seeing.